# Simulating Customer/Employee Threads using Queues and Semaphores

Tags: java, queue, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I need quite a bit of help. So the task is to simulate a coffee shop. It's a coffee shop with 5 seats. If you arrive while there is an empty seat, you can take a seat immediately. But if you arrive when all 5 seats are full, that means that all of the customers are having coffee 
together, and you will have to wait for the entire party to leave (all 5 seats to become free) before you sit down.

This has to be enforced using Threads. The amount of customers is passed in as a command line argument.

Anyways, I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about this.

I was thinking - should I use the provided Semaphore class and do I make two Queues of type "CustomerThread" and have one of them be the queue for the customers currently drinking, and another queue for customers waiting in line? Or should the ones waiting in line be a BlockedQueue? However, I'm not sure how to enforce the 5 seat rule. For example if say two threads finish and leave the shop, there'll be two seats open, but until all 5 are open, we can't add the next five to the drinking queue and remove from the waiting queue.

Comment: I wouldn't put those drinking/sitting in a queue. The queue(s) are for waiting. There must be something that determines how long they sit and drink so just let them run. The 5 seat rule can be accomplished with an outer lock on the logic that process incoming customers. It would be set when the all 5 seats are taken and released when all are gone.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth looking at [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), they are easier to customise than `Semaphores`, if you didn't have the requirement of ( when it is full we need to wait for the shop to be completely empty) then a `Semaphore` would have been the best, we create a `Semaphore` with 5 `permits` and we `await` when people enter and `release` when they leave. But with these constraints a `Condition` might be a better choice.

Something like that.

```
 static class CoffeeShop{
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    private int counter = 0;
    public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        try{
            lock.lock();
            if(counter<5){
                System.out.println(" in "+""+counter);
                ++counter;
            }else if(counter==5){
                System.out.println("shop is full");
                while (counter>0) {
                    condition.await();
                }
                ++counter;
                System.out.println(" in "+""+counter);
            }
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void leave(){
        try{
            lock.lock();
            --counter;
            if(counter==0){
             condition.signal();
            }
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to have your own waiting queue, because `Condition` maintains a waiting thread queue for you.